# how to merge 3 lists into a list like a table data in java

Tags: java, collections

Let suppose i have three different list of string type data which I fetched from a table (different Columns). Now I want to add these three lists like a table data in third list. Please suggest.

```
List<String> allData = new LinkedList<>();
List<String> list1 = new LinkedList<>();
List<String> list2 = new LinkedList<>();
List<String> list3 = new LinkedList<>();
    
list1.add("1");
list1.add("2");
        
list2.add("3");
list2.add("4");
        
list3.add("5");
list3.add("6");
```

Comment: What do you expect ? `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]` ?

Comment: I expect [ (1,3,5),(2,4,6)]

Comment: so a list of list ?

Comment: Please share what have you **tried** and specify what are the issues you've encountered?

Comment: I tried, though two for each loops but not getting the way i want.

Comment: `I tried, though two for each loops` - Then share your code. It's always highly advisable to include your attempt into a question, see [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: These lists are of the same size?

Comment: Yes all three lists are of same size.

Comment: for (List<K> list : listOfLists) {
            System.out.print("  [");
  
            for (K item : list) {
                System.out.print("  "
                                 + item
                                 + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println("], ");
        }
        System.out.println("]");

Comment: @RishiSharma It seems like this code is unrelated to question. Please find the proper code and add it to the question (use *edit* button, or this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73837939/edit)).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248320/discussion-between-rishi-sharma-and-alexander-ivanchenko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the same indice for each and collect in a new one

```
List<String> list1 = List.of("1", "2");
List<String> list2 = List.of("3", "4");
List<String> list3 = List.of("5", "6");
List<List<String>> allLists = List.of(list1, list2, list3);

List<List<String>> allData = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<String> someList : allLists) {
        tmp.add(someList.get(i));
    }
    allData.add(tmp);
}

System.out.println(allData);
// [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all lists are of the same size, you can combine an arbitrary number of the lists joining elements under the same index that using Stream API.

For that, you can create a stream over the *indices*, and then for every index create a stream of list elements that correspond to that index.

Collect each nested stream into a list applying Java 16 `toList()` or `collect(Collectors.toList())`, and then collect all the list into a nested list.

Here's a generic implementation:

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <T> List<List<T>> joinAllByIndex(List<T>... lists) {
    if (lists.length == 0) return Collections.emptyList();
    
    return IntStream.range(0, lists[0].size())
        .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.stream(lists)
            .map(list -> list.get(i))
            .toList())
        .toList(); // for Java 16+ or collect(Collectors.toList()) for earlier versions
}
```